# UIWebView inside UIPageViewController crashes app

Tags: swift, iframe, uiwebview, uitextview, uipageviewcontroller

I have an app which needs a fix for the crash details below. Flow goes like this , user launches app, news articles are displayed on `uitableview` each cell has one article details. When user clicks on any cell we set all articles on `uipageviewcontroller` using  `pageViewController.setViewControllers([newsDetails!], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)`

If the articles are displayed only on text view, swiping controller to left and right works perfectly. But if there are 2 consecutive web view articles, swipe right (from web view article move to next web view article) and then left (back to web view article) the app crashes with this [crash log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzLna.png).

Just to experiment I put my data into textview instead of uiwebview and it still crashed with same crash log, this articles use iframe tag in it. Code is here :

```
  func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Returning the article's detail view controller for the previous index
        print("VIEW CONTROLLER AFTER")
        return articleDetailViewController(for: detailPageIndex()-1,fromDetail:false)
    }

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Returning the article's detail view controller for the next index
        print("VIEW CONTROLLER BEFORE")

        return articleDetailViewController(for: detailPageIndex()+1,fromDetail:false)
    }

// We create a new instance of detail View Controller when ever a new VC is requested 

func articleDetailViewController(for index: Int,fromDetail :Bool) -> MISNewsDetailViewController? {
        let allNews:Bool
         if(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "IsAllNewsSelected") == nil || (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "IsAllNewsSelected") as! String) == "YES"){
            allNews = true
         }else{
            allNews = false
        }
        //--------------------------------------------
        // If the index is out of bound, nil is return
        if(allNews){
            if (index == -1 || index >= (allArticles.count)) {
                return nil
            }
        }else{
            if (index == -1 || index >= (myArticles.count)) {
                return nil
            }
        }

        //---------------------------------------------------
        // Getting the article object for the requested index
        let article: MISArticle?
        let detailViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MISNewsDetailViewController") as? MISNewsDetailViewController

        let myAppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
        if(myAppDelegate.isLaunchedFromWidget){
            article =  self.getTheWidgetSelectedArticleBaasedOnGlobalId();
        }else{
            if(allNews){
                article = allArticles[index]
                 detailViewController?.isAllNewsPost = true
            }else{
                article = myArticles[index]
                 detailViewController?.isAllNewsPost = false
            }
        }

        detailViewController?.mPost = article
        detailViewController?.isRefreshPost = fromDetail
        return detailViewController
    }
```

Comment: Share the crash log.

Comment: I have edited the post, attached a screenshot for Stack Trace. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you have a detailPageIndex() not clear here. Is this detailPageIndex dependent on allArticles or myArticles? It's better to separate two logics with two functions.

Comment: detailPageIndex only returns the index of array allArticles and myArticles.